# How to list/group post by date in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, grouping

I have a table with a list of events (postings). All the event have a date datatype with start_date and end_date of the events.

I to display the list of events with the events that will be happening first. So for example, I have an event that's starting on November 12th and then a few on November 13, 14 and so on. I want to display the ones that will be happening first. How can I reorder it?

Here's my code now:

```
<tbody>
    <% @events.each do |event| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= event.image %>" height="50" width="50"></td>
        <td> <%= link_to event.title, event %></td>

        <td><%= event.category %></td>


        <td> <%= event.start_date %> / <%= event.end_dates %></td>




      </tr>
```

My controller is just:

```
 def index
    @events = Event.all
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller:

```
def index
  @events = Event.order(:start_date)
end
```

You may want to go through the [Active Record Basics Page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html)